# Removing sensitive data from SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration

We have data stored in encrypted fields (with SQL Server encryption) in our database and we have a requirement to be able to remove certain records from our database under certain peculiar conditions that I will spare you. However it has been noted by a DBA that simply nulling out the data potentially still leaves residual data in the file so it could potentially be recovered.

It has been suggested by someone in the team that (rather than nulling) we write a '*' for each character we want to remove then delete the record, and they assert that this will wipe the data so if someone gets hold of the mdf file the value won't be retrievable (because the bits have been overwritten). For example if we have a value "abc" we run an update statement that replaces this value with '***'. Then we delete the record.

Can anyone confirm if this is the case? Personally I'm skeptical, but I'm a developer and not a DBA so this isn't an area of specialty for me.

Comment: First off, if you are concerned about someone reading the .MDF directly, you have far bigger concerns than residual sensitive data. Ensuring that the database files are not accessible to anyone except qualified individuals is an absolute necessity regardless. For starters, anyone with access to the transaction log or backup files can read old values of rows, regardless of how you overwrite them with anything. Either you have secured your files or you haven't -- if you have, jumping through extra hoops with overwriting data doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: Second, all this tricksy updating still isn't good enough. If SQL Server needs to split a page to insert rows, it will copy data on its own, potentially leaving old data behind on the page. Barring exceptionally precise database design, you don't know when page splits happen and no amount of tricky data manipulation is going to erase the data left behind by them. If you really want secure database files, you want to look at things like [Always Encrypted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163865.aspx), which is designed for it. The regular engine, not so much.

Comment: And this is really a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com (see [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49261) for example) and I shouldn't be answering questions in comments. So bad me. :-)